# how can i tell (in bash script) if a clonezilla batch mode backup succeeded?

Tags: linux, bash, backup, clonezilla

I'm using slightly customized Clonezilla-Live cd's to backup the drives on four PCs.  Each cd is for a specific PC, saving an image of its disk(s) to a box-specific backup folder on a samba server.  That's all pretty much working.  But once in a while, Something Goes Wrong, and the backup isn't completed properly.  Things like: the cat bit through a cat5e cable; I forgot to check if the samba server had run out of room; etc.  And it is not always readily apparent that a failure happened.

I will admit right now that I am pretty much a noob as far as linux system administration goes, even though i managed somehow to setup a centos 6 box (i wish i'd picked ubuntu...) with samba, git, ssh, and bitnami-gitlab back in february.

I've spent days and days and days trying to figure out if clonezilla leaves a simple clue in a backup as to whether it succeeded completely or not, and have come up dry.  Looking in the folder for a particular backup job (on the samba server) I see that the last file written is named "clonezilla-img".  It seems to be a console dump that covers the backup itself.  But it does not seem to include the verification pass.

Regardless of whether the batch backup task succeeded or failed, I can run a post-process bash script automagically, that I place on my clonezilla cds.  I have this set to run just fine, though its not doing a whole lot right now.  What I would like this post-process script to do is determine if the backup job succeeded or not, and then rename (mv) the backup job directory to include some word like "SUCCESS" or "FAILURE".  I know how to do the renaming part.  It's the test for success or failure that I'm at a loss about.

Answer (score 1):

For your case I think you could do what you are looking for with `ocs_prerun` and `ocs_postrun` scripts.

For my setup I'm using a pen/falsh drive for some test systems and also pxe with NFSmount. PXE and nfs are much easier to test and modify quickly.

I haven't tested this yet, but I was thinking that I might be able to search the logs in /var/log/{clonezilla.log, partclone.log} via an ocs_postrun script to validate success or failure. I haven't seen anything that indicates the result is set in the environment so I'm thinking the logs might be the quick easy method over mounting or running a crc check. Clonezilla does have an option to validate the image, the results of which might be in the local logs.

Another option might be to create a custom ocs_live_run script to do something similar. There is an example at this URL http://clonezilla.org/fine-print-live-doc.php?path=./clonezilla-live/doc/07_Customized_script_with_PXE/00_customized_script_with_PXE.doc#00_customized_script_with_PXE.doc

Maybe in the script the exit code of ocs-sr can be checked? As I said I haven't tried any of this, just some thoughts.

I updated the above to reflect the log location (/var/log). The logs are in the log folder of course.